# How to control who read a sharepoint announcement?

Tags: c#, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

### Requirements

I have an site hierarchy where the root site is the "Project Management Site" and each subsite is the "Project Site", so, subsites will be: Project1, Project2, Project3, etc.

A manager needs to create an announcement in the root, the announcement will be for everyone or for specific project (subsite). Currently i see two options:

### Approach 1

One announcements list in the root site, every subsite will read announcements from this announcements list.

### Approach 2

One announcements list in the root and one event receiver to copy items from this list for each (or specific subsite).

> I have some code written for the Approach 2, but i can easily change it.

### My question is:

How can i manage who (user) already read the announcement? Will i need to create another list (kind of middle-entity) to manage this?

Comment: What do you mean by managing who Reaed the announcement ? You need a record of who read it ? How are you showing the alerts to the users ? as a web part or in a list ?

Comment: Yes @SigarDave. Iif a user logs in and he/she has not read the announcement i will show it in red, if he/she already read the announcement I will show it in green. I will develop a custom webpart to show the announcement.

Comment: Ok Understood, you can do two things 1. is to maintain a list of users who read the alert by adding them in sql table, but for that you need to have a custom sql db . 2. Or you can add a custom User Profile property for the SPuser. So that when a person has read the alert, at that time you can set a value for that property to true.

Here is the code to do that. 
http://dhirendrayadav.com/2010/06/adding-custom-user-profile-properties.html

Comment: @SigarDave A custom SQL DB seems excessive. This is SharePoint... OP can just create entries in a custom SharePoint list via JavaScript if needed.

Comment: @Ewerton How "secure" do the announcements need to be? Is it enough to hide irrelevant announcements from projects that they don't pertain to, or is there sensitive information in the announcements that must not be seen by members of other project teams?

Comment: @thriggle , i do agree with that sql comment, but that is a suggestion and it  may be easy to play with the data in that case. Also If I will be the one then I will go for the custom property way

Comment: I do not think other SQL DB or the User profile solution is a good idea, i see it as a oversized solution for a simple problem. If i need to crate another "way" os control who reade the announcement, i can create another hidden list in sharepoint. In fact i am asking this question to know if Sharepoint already have this kind of control. If i need to create another list, i will do, but if sharepoint already have some OOB solution for this problem, it will be better.